# Xcode debugging AppleScript

Tags: xcode, debugging, applescript

Xcode has apparently AppleScript debugging facilities :

- You can put breakpoints
- Executable options mentions AppleScript Debugger

But I could not figure how to Run & Debug script...

Tried setting up a custom executable calling osascript with script as argument, breakpoints are not hit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to myself to close this one...

From what I have found on the web, Cocoa AppleScript based applications / AppleScript Studio are being abandoned by Apple. All Applescript references in recent versions of Xcode (v3.2+) would just be remainings from that past and should not be working anymore. And from what I see, there is no reference to AppleScript in Xcode 4... (except maybe file association/syntax coloring)

So the only option I see to debug AppleScript, *without using third party tools*, is using that (*uneffective*) old debug-logging-technique: `log xxx`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a similar position. I'm new to XCode and have successfully followed the "Hello World" tutorial which includes guidance for debugging.

I then created a Project based on Cocoa-Applescript Application and selected the MyScriptAppDelegate.applescript file that results from this action. This script window presents pre loaded script that advises where my script code can be placed. Once this is done it is possible to 'Run' the script using the 'Run' and or 'Build and Debug' buttons.

It is also possible to insert a breakpoint icon in the left hand column as with the normal Cocoa project. However when the Debugger is run the breakpoints do not trigger. The code runs to completion as if the 'Run - Breakpoints Off' menu item is selected. Clicking the "Debug - Breakpoints On" menu item will also run the script but appears to function exactly like 'Run - Breakpoints Off'.

Comment: From what I have read on the web, Cocoa AppleScript based applications / AppleScript Studio are being abandoned. There is no reference to AppleScript in Xcode 4... Anyway, `log xxx` works to debug, just less convenient. That did the job for me. (using `say` works also and is fun btw :)